# Convert all the keys and values of a Map to String in Dart

Tags: json, dictionary, dart, flutter

The problem I am having is related to serialization and decoding JSON. I am trying to serialize a Protobuf message to use it with redux persist.

This is the method I call to serialize my object:

```
  Map<String, dynamic> toJSON(){

    return <String, dynamic>{
        'isLogged': this.isLogged,
        'isExpired': this.isExpired,
        'protoUser':
            this.protoUser == null ? null : this.protoUser.writeToJsonMap()),
        'error': this.error,
      }
  };
```

and this is the method I use to read the persisted state:

```
  factory AuthState.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    new AuthState(
      isLogged: json['isLogged'],
      isExpired: json['isExpired'],
      error: json['error'],
      protoUser: json['protoUser'] == null
          ? null
          : new Auth.fromJson(json['protoUser'].toString()),
    );
  }
```

The problem I have is that `writeToJsonMap` do not write a valid JSON map for dart. So when reading the serialized state, I get this error:

```
E/flutter (24643): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)
E/flutter (24643): {1: 200, 2: test1, 3: test2, 4: {1: 1, 3: Mike, 4: tester}}
```

also asked on https://github.com/dart-lang/protobuf/issues/136

Comment: "So when reading the serialized state" what does that mean?

Comment: redux persist is package to save redux store which contains the state of app. I mean when reading the serialized file.

Comment: You're doing something wrong, but it's probably something in code not included in your question.

Comment: it is similar to https://github.com/FranPitri/flutter_redux_boilerplate
 ... the one difference is that instead of using User model, I used a protobuf object.

Comment: and everything works if I remove protoUser (where the json coding/deconding is wrong)

Comment: That looks like JSON encoding for protobuf transport not for custom use. Protobuf uses numeric indices for fields to save space.

Comment: Exactly, I am trying to find a workaround to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is a pull request for allowing field names. 
https://github.com/dart-lang/protobuf/pull/83